# Dependency issue with Maven

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I've a Maven project that I want to test using Junit, Mockito and Cucumber, but I've a big problem with the dependencies. The project has no problem with this maven command: clean install package -X with skip tests.

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding Jackson libraries indeed, your pom has this:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>         
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

jackson-databind comes from fasterxml and has explicit version while other members come from codehaus and have not. 
Basically your pom is pretty messy, I would suggest t clean it up, it will be twice smaller after that. 
For instance Spring framework also contains Jackson libraries in its modules and re-importing it again is not required or even not recommended but your Spring dependencies are the same messy as the rest of it so its hard to say what's pulled actually. 
Try to examine your effective pom first and remove or exclude all duplicates, especially from different vendors.